# WMS and Quantum GIS/ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I periodically use a nice basemap served by the Utah state government in QGIS. Recently they upgraded their server from ArcGIS Server 9.3 to ArcGIS Server 10.1. Ever since then, I can't seem to get the WMS basemap to load in QGIS in the same way. Previously I would get nice raster tiles of Utah. Now I just get plain county, municipal, and road identification layers without the pretty images. All of WMS basemaps I've tried from their server seem to work fine in ArcGIS, though.

Am I missing something? The URL to the basemap I generally use is below.

http://mapserv.utah.gov/arcgis/services/BaseMaps/Vector/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Comment: above link is working fine on machine (QGIS 1.8 and Win 7). They might updated the service

Comment: Also works on QGIS 1.9.

Comment: Doesn't work here either, Ubuntu 12.04, QGIS Master. Like you, all I get are the counties, roads and municipalities.

Comment: Figured it out. My ignorance: It has to do with the layer order. Inverting the order displays the map properly.